# Storing Current Running Threads and then returning those values

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium

I am looking to achieve the following - User specifies how many threads to run at the same time and a csv file with a list of accounts. It goes one by one through each account and does the runnable action With each of the accounts. What I am looking to do is keep track of the current running threads number so that I can run each thread with a specific exe. So if I was running 5 threads at the same time it would be able to use driver1.exe, driver2.exe, driver3.exe, driver4.exe, driver5.exe. Below is how I am handling grabbing data and passing it to the thread.

```
public class MoveSpam 
{
    static int j = 0;
    public static boolean maxThreadsWait = false;
    public static int currentThreads = 0;
    public static int threadnum = 0;

    //static int numthr = ;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        String username = null;  
        String password = null;
        String recoveryEmail = null;
        String recoveryPhone = null;
        String cookie = null;
        int localthread = 0;

        //System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir/required/"));
        // System.out.print();
        int threadCount = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        ArrayList<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        AccountData accountData = new AccountData();
        accountData.loadDataFromFile((args[0]));
        System.out.println("Number of Accounts: "+accountData.getNumberOfAccounts());
        int vals = accountData.getNumberOfAccounts();

        final int numThreads = 5;
       // ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
        //ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
        for( j = 0; j <vals; j++ )
        {

        int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, vals );
        String accountInfo = accountData.getAccountNumber(randomNum).toString();
        String[] currentAccount;
        String delimiter = ",";
        currentAccount = accountInfo.split(delimiter);
        username = currentAccount[0];   
        password = currentAccount[1];
        recoveryEmail = currentAccount[2];
        recoveryPhone = currentAccount[3];
        cookie = currentAccount[4];
        System.out.println("Processing Account: "+ currentAccount[0]+","+currentAccount[1]+","+currentAccount[2]+","+currentAccount[3]+","+currentAccount[4]);


        //ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        if (currentThreads < threadCount ){
            Runnable worker = new GmailMover(currentAccount[0],currentAccount[1], currentAccount[2], currentAccount[3], currentAccount[4], j);
            currentThreads ++;
            //threads.get(j).start();
            executor.execute(worker);


        }else{
            while (currentThreads >= threadCount){
                try {
                    System.out.println("Waiting 1000 MS");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
            System.out.println("Spawning New Account");
            System.out.println("Number of threads ran:");

}

        }


        System.out.println("Cleared All inboxes! :)");  
    }
}
```

The Input number will change each time so don't wanna set up a case for each and am doing the following in another class.

```
public class GmailMover implements Runnable{
    WebDriver driver = null;
    String localusername = null;  
    String localpassword = null; 
    String localrecoveryemail = null; 
    String localrecoveryphone = null; 
    String localcookie = null; 
    int localthread = 0;
    boolean localTrigger = false;
    String status = null;
    public void run(){  
        System.out.print(localthread);
        String workingdir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        workingdir = workingdir+"\\required";
        ///START
        String Browser = workingdir + "\\Selenium\\geckodriver"+localthread+".exe";
        System.out.println(Browser);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", workingdir + "\\Selenium\\geckodriver"+localthread+".exe");//Set Browser
```

Right now I have it set up to pass a the thread number to thread, but I cannot figure out how to return it back so it will keep the value and I can launch another thread using the returned value. So an example would be if thread 7 finished(Which was using driver7.exe) the next thread to launch would be assigned 7 and then launch driver7.exe again. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could use the `Callable` interface to return the value from the class doing the work. Its pretty much the same as `Runnable`, but allows you to return things

Comment: When calling threads async then you should return a `Future` that is holding the value. Don't allow multiple threads run one by run by providing a blocking queue to the executor service.

Comment: Okay I can get it to return values but storing it so it can compare if it's already being used in not sure how to do.